# What stuff gets used in rituals?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

As far as I know, most of the "rituals" that are mentioned don't include a list of ingredients (because I think they're not *actually* required). Do any of the books include a list of things that would actually be used for rituals?

Comment: As in the ones in core? Page ref would be nice.
You mean things like Exorcisms, right?

Comment: @Oxinabox I'm being very general, character is running a *Magic* shop, I'm mostly looking into it for the purpose of adding fluff. The kinds of things customers might request as specialty items.

Comment: right. Ok. Are answers that refer to things that have no actual magical properties Ok?
For example I know a Mage going on a asteral journey needs to succeed on a hard extended action meditation roll.
Incense and calming music and a yoga mat all give about a +1 to the roll.
Also certain Mage magics require things like Crystal balls, or Pools of water to scry though.
There is a Demon power (I can't remember which), the to activate the PC had to do something to focus. This particular PC chain-smoked. For him his tobacco was magic. These object are more or less useless on their own.

Comment: @Oxinabox I would guess that *most* of the things in the shop are going to be things that have no magical properties. We did give her "Esoteric Armory". Also thinking of things for werewolf rituals, circle of the crone, etc. So I'm betting that although they might be *useless* on their own, not all of them are the kinds of things you want the cops knowing you have. She might have a few imbued, or fetish, etc, items, but she currently isn't aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p141 of Hunter: Witch Finders

> The tier of the spell affects the quality and rarity of the
>   exotic ingredients that must be gathered in preparation of,
>   and for use during, the ritual.
>
> Tier one ingredient examples: toadstools, incense, pure
>   water, various herbs, ritual tools (athame, wand, chalice,
>   sword), sympathetic representations of the target (pictures,
>   voodoo dolls) and candles.
>
> Tier two ingredient examples: eye of newt, blood from an
>   unborn child, tears from a virgin, ashes from the combined burn-
>   ing of the sacred woods, continual recitation of the name(s) of
>   the target, use of glyphs and sigils and animal sacrifice.
>
> Tier three ingredients examples: fresh hemlock flowers
>   gathered during the dark of the moon, a physical representation of the target carved from the wood of Yggdrasil, an apology from the unrepentant, the horn from a demon, bodily fluids of a saint, a vial of water taken from the Sea of Tranquility and human sacrifice.